# How disable direct ip access in Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

I have a website with CloudFlare protection, seems good at too, but if you enter the original IP adress of my server you can enter normally.

I'm using Apache (XAMPP) and SSL (https://)

I want something similar when you enter from the IP address with CloudFlare, which throws error 1003

Comment: [so] is for programming questions. [sf] or [webmasters.se] are better places to ask about webserver configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You can verify if the domain received in the request matches your site domain.  If not, force a redirection to the user. Like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

So IP accesses will be forced back to the domain name.
Obviously, you could return anything, this is just one method I see often.

Answer (score 2):

Edit or create a default vhost and put this inside:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Redirect 403 /
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your server ip address

After that restart your apache

```
sudo a2ensite your-vhost.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Hope that helps